# JQuery Data table - Get a value of a different column from another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

How do I get the value of `checklistclient_id` column and insert into the `onchange` event at the last column?
When the change of checkbox value occurs, it brings the `checklistclient_id` to the `togglecheck` function.

```
function loadClientChecklist(url){
var rt_hash = decodeUrl(url);
var id = rt_hash[0].replace("id=", "");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../model/get_set_ajax2.php?req=21',
    data: 'cid=' + id,
    success: function (results) {
        console.log(results);
        $('#clchecklist_tab').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "searching": true,
            "info": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "aaData": $.parseJSON(results),
            "aoColumns": [
                {"mData": "checklistclient_id", "visible": false},
                {"mData": "description"},
                {"mData": "is_checked", "mRender": function (data) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" onchange="togglecheck('+ checklistclient_id +')" value='+data+'/>';

                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [row created callback](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) Then you can set id to trs.

```
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
    $(row).data("checklistclient_id", checklistclient_id );
 }
```

Now, you know all id of tr. Lets say that your check box has class called cb

```
$("#clchecklist_tab" ).delegate( ".cb", "change", function() {
    togglecheck($(this).closest("tr").data(checklistclient_id))
})"
```